# 22.04 Webcam permissions are reset on boot

Tags: permissions, 22.04, webcam

I can only access my webcam(s) with sudo rights with cheese.

```
ls -l /dev/video0
```

outputs:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Nov 13 15:18 /dev/video0
```

same for `video1`.
When setting

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/video*
```

(or 660) changes are accepted

```
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root video 81, 0 Nov 13 15:18 /dev/video0
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root video 81, 0 Nov 13 15:18 /dev/video1
```

However this does not change the fact, that cheese does only find webcam(s) when run with sudo rights. When rebooting, the old permissions on `video*` are reset to what they were before.
I also added my user to the group `video`. This however survives a reboot but does not solve my issue.

Comment: Normally, you shouldn't need to mess up with permissions of these devices. Read+Write permission to these files is automatically given to the user who has control of the console (physical screen). Do you see the `+` at the end of permissions lists in your question? You can see these extra (`+`) permissions using the `getfacl /dev/video*` command. You should see a line like this: `user:youruser:rw-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than your current approach, add yourself to the `video` group. Do:

```
device="/dev/video0"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

See `man newgrp`.

Comment: I don't think we need all these. My system works as I explained in my comment to the question. I have a "simple" (non-admin) user with no other group membership and it works like this.